# AZURE Event Hub processing multiple protocols to same Topic

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

Upon reading on AZURE Event Hub,

- I note that we can send data via

  - http(s)
  - AMQP
  - KAFKA

As I am not an integration (messaging) expert, the following then:

- Can I use both AMQP and http(s) to write to the same Event Hub Topic
- and subsequently can a single AZURE Function read from that same single Event Hub Topic regardless of how written to?
- For KAFKA, this will need to be always a separate Event Hub (Topic) is my understanding.

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-exchange-events-different-protocols) might be of interest to you.

Comment: @PeterBons. I read that some time ago but was unsure. For tibco ems with java jms to write ibm mq i know i need the corresponding java jms read fir ibm mq. So?

Comment: I think i get it but we have a feed already that is kafka as json. Should be ok i think. @PeterBons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AZURE EVENT HUB KAFKA look-like API means that, if you, say, all send a JSON format using all 3 protocols, they can be mapped to the same Event Hub (= Topic), and one can read the Event Hub in KAFKA mode, say.

This is a good read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-exchange-events-different-protocols  but I checked with a more experienced person to confirm.